# How to get staff schedule for a given week

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have following tables in my project to store staff working schedule and holidays.

Here is my database schema and some data, and a  [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d5cda) of same:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE schedules (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    day_of_week INT NOT NULL,
    start_date VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    end_date VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

-- data
INSERT INTO schedules
    (id, user_id, day_of_week,start_date,end_date)
VALUES
    (1, 2,1,"2021-05-03","2021-05-24"),
    (2, 2,1,"2021-05-31","2021-05-31"),
    (3, 2,1,"2021-06-07",null),
    (4, 2,2,"2021-05-04",null),
    (5, 2,3,"2021-05-05",null),
    (6, 2,4,"2021-05-06",null),
    (7, 2,5,"2021-05-07",null),
    (8, 2,6,"2021-05-08",null),
    (9, 3,1,"2021-04-12","2021-05-31"),
    (10, 3,1,"2021-06-07",null),
    (11, 3,2,"2021-05-11","2021-06-08"),
    (12, 3,2,"2021-06-15",null),
    (13, 3,3,"2021-05-05",null),
    (14, 3,4,"2021-05-06",null),
    (15, 3,5,"2021-05-07",null),
    (16, 3,6,"2021-05-08",null);
```

I could not figure out how to get staff schedule data if staff is working on given week or day.

Expected result should be like below for different weeks

```
2021-05-09 to 2021-05-21

+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       2 |           1 | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-24 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  9 |       3 |           1 | 2021-04-12 | 2021-05-31 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+

2021-05-30 to 2021-06-05

+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |       2 |           1 | 2021-05-31 | 2021-05-31 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 10 |       3 |           1 | 2021-06-07 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+

2021-06-13 to 2021-06-19

+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  3 |       2 |           1 | 2021-06-07 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| 10 |       3 |           1 | 2021-06-07 | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

currently I am running following query in incremental loop from `2021-06-13` to `2021-06-19` in `Laravel`

```
select
  *
from
`schedules`
where
  and `start_date` <= '2021-05-13' // 2021-05-14,2021-05-15 etc.
  and `day_of_week` = 0 // 1,2,3 etc.
  and (
    `end_date` >= '2021-05-18'
    or `end_date` is null )
```

Following is my code in `Laravel` for same

```
    $start_date = new Carbon($data['start_date']);
    $start_date->startOfWeek(Carbon::SUNDAY);

    $schedule = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {

        $schedule[] = StaffSchedule::
            where('start_date', '<=', $start_date->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->where('day_of_week',$start_date->dayOfWeek)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($start_date) {
                $query->where('end_date','>=',$start_date->format('Y-m-d'));
                $query->orWhereNull('end_date');
            })->orderBy('user_id')->get();

        $start_date = $start_date->addDay();
    }
```

Above code runs 7 queries, 1 for each day of the week.

Is it possible to combine and run single query?

Thank you

Comment: Trying to display weekly schedule of staff for given week. For example current week starting from `2021-06-06 to `2021-06-12` for user 2 query should return row 3. for week starting from `2021-05-16` to `2021-05-21` query should return row 1.

Comment: @Strawberry updated the question, data set from [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/736c3b3) is correct.

Comment: @Strawberry basically I would like to know which users are working or not by passing week start date and end date.

Comment: @Strawberry there are other fields in the `schedules` table like `location_id`,`shift_start_time` and `shift_end_time`,`break_at` etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, consider the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM schedules 
 WHERE start_date <= '2021-05-15' 
   AND COALESCE(end_date,start_date) >= '2021-05-09';
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |       2 |           1 | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-24 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+

SELECT * 
  FROM schedules 
 WHERE start_date <= '2021-06-05' 
   AND COALESCE(end_date,start_date) >= '2021-05-31';
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  2 |       2 |           1 | 2021-05-31 | 2021-05-31 |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+

SELECT * 
  FROM schedules 
 WHERE start_date <= '2021-06-06' + INTERVAL 1 WEEK 
   AND COALESCE(end_date,start_date) >= '2021-06-06';
+----+---------+-------------+------------+----------+
| id | user_id | day_of_week | start_date | end_date |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+----------+
|  3 |       2 |           1 | 2021-06-07 | NULL     |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: It does with a minor tweak

Comment: without querying the result I am not sure if the `end_date` field is null or not so how would I know which query to use??

Comment: They're all the same with respect to end_date - but I'll edit the last one by way of a hint...

Comment: I have updated the question and included expected result as well.